# Sending data using jquery/ajax to mvc controller

Tags: jquery, .net, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Inside my MVC application this is my model:

```
public class Student
    {
        public string StudentId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }
```

My .cshtml is like:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(null, "TestAjaxBeginForm", null , null))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Student</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StudentId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StudentId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StudentId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" onclick="GetData()"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

I am using jquery to send data in controller from .cshtml file.

```
<script>
    function GetData()
    {
        debugger;
         var Student = [
        {
            'StudentId': $('#StudentId').val(),
            'Name': $('#Name').val(),
            'Address': $('#Address').val()
        }
        ];
        Student = JSON.stringify({ 'Student': Student });

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Student/GetData/",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: Student,
            processData: true,
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Hi");
                //alert(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, error) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert("Error: " + xhr.responseText);
                //alert(error);
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

And my controller is:

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetData(Student Student)
    {
        var StudentId = Student.StudentId.ToString();
        var StudentName = Student.Name.ToString();
        var Address = Student.Address.ToString();
        return Json(JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I my getting form data inside jscript function, but inside controller(GetData) values of StudentId, StudentName and address are showing null.
Any help will be thankfully accepted.

Thanks
Partha

Comment: Your method accepts a single object, not a collection so its `var Student = { ... };` (no square brackets). But you can simplify all this by just using `data: $('form').serialize(),` and delete the `contentType` option. But what are you trying to do here - you have `Ajax.BeginForm()` and `$.ajax()` so you making 2 ajax calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing it to the following should work:

```
    var Student = 
    {
        StudentId: $('[name="StudentId"').val(),
        Name: $('[name="Name"]').val(),
        Address: $('[name="Address"]').val()
    }
```

Also there is no need for the `JSON.stringify` call